# Python - Calculate vertices from a PNG file according to its color

Tags: python, pygame, pygame-surface

This is the image I have:
[image]

With this image I have a square grid, and I was wondering if there is a way to calculate the vertices from the brown objects without it being hardcoded. How can I do that with Python and Pygame?

Comment: There is no feature built into Pygame. If you want to do so, have a look into [OpenCV - Hough Line Transform](https://docs.opencv.org/master/d9/db0/tutorial_hough_lines.html). For OpenCV in Python you can use [opencv-python](https://pypi.org/project/opencv-python/)

Answer (score 2):

The map consists of square tiles with a size of 64. The color of the brown objects is RGB(90, 40, 2) and the color of the green objects is RGB(57, 214, 105).

Create a grid by reading 1 pixel in the center of each tile and comparing it to the brown color:

```py
map_image = pygame.image.load("KkiJJ.png")
map_size = map_image.get_size()

tile_size = 64
grid = []
for x in range(map_size[0] // tile_size):
    column = [] 
    for y in range(map_size[1] // tile_size):
        color = map_image.get_at((x*tile_size + tile_size//2, y*tile_size + tile_size//2))
        if color.r == 90 and color.g == 44 and color.b == 2:
            column.append(1)
        else:
            column.append(0)
    grid.append(column)
```

The coordinates of the tile in the `c` column and the `r` line can be represented by the `pygame.Rect` object:

```py
r = pygame.Rect(c * tile_size, r * tile_size, tile_size, tile_size)
```